# In-place Compression of IntervalIndex'd Pandas Series with Repeated Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data-frame with a IntervalIndex.  Some of the columns will have several connecting intervals with the same data, and I would like to break the data-frame into a dictionary of series and then do an in-place compression where I merge adjacent intervals that have the same data value.

I have what I think is a pretty ugly solution using a while loop and a list of compressed intervals as a hack around the fact that an IntervalIndex is immutable.  I am not posting this on code review because I think it is just terrible.  Only posting here because it shows what I am trying to do.

Is there some built-in function that I am unaware of or maybe a more pythonic combination I can use to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

# create data
index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
data = {"a": [1, 2, 3, 4], "b": [5, 5, 6, 6], "c": [7, 7, 7, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data)

# break dataframe into a dict of series to we can compress
dict_of_series = df.to_dict("series")

# combine overlapping bins with redundant data
def compress(s):

    # we need to build the compressed index rather than modify in-place, as IntervalIndex is immuatable
    compressed_index = [s.index[0]]

    i = 1
    while True:
        try:
            i0 = s.index[i - 1]
            i1 = s.index[i]
            d0 = s.iloc[i - 1]
            d1 = s.iloc[i]
        except IndexError:
            break

        # if intervals don't touch, we cannot combine bins
        if compressed_index[-1].right < i1.left:
            compressed_index.append(i1)
            i += 1
            continue

        # if intervals touch and the data is the same, combine bins
        if d0 == d1:
            s.drop(i1, inplace=True)

            compressed_index[-1] = pd.Interval(compressed_index[-1].left, i1.right)
            continue

        compressed_index.append(i1)
        i += 1

    # replace the index with the compressed index we built
    s.index = pd.IntervalIndex(compressed_index)


print("Original Data for 'a'")
print(dict_of_series["a"])
print()
print("Compressed Data for 'a'")
compress(dict_of_series["a"])
print(dict_of_series["a"])
print()
print("Original Data for 'b'")
print(dict_of_series["b"])
print()
print("Compressed Data for 'b'")
compress(dict_of_series["b"])
print(dict_of_series["b"])
print()
print("Original Data for 'c'")
print(dict_of_series["c"])
print()
print("Compressed Data for 'c'")
compress(dict_of_series["c"])
print(dict_of_series["c"])
```

Which gives the following result:

```
Original Data for 'a'
(1, 2]    1
(2, 3]    2
(3, 4]    3
(4, 5]    4
Name: a, dtype: int64

Compressed Data for 'a'
(1, 2]    1
(2, 3]    2
(3, 4]    3
(4, 5]    4
Name: a, dtype: int64

Original Data for 'b'
(1, 2]    5
(2, 3]    5
(3, 4]    6
(4, 5]    6
Name: b, dtype: int64

Compressed Data for 'b'
(1, 3]    5
(3, 5]    6
Name: b, dtype: int64

Original Data for 'c'
(1, 2]    7
(2, 3]    7
(3, 4]    7
(4, 5]    7
Name: c, dtype: int64

Compressed Data for 'c'
(1, 5]    7
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
>>> df.loc[~df['a'].duplicated(), 'a']
(1, 2]    1
(2, 3]    2
(3, 4]    3
(4, 5]    4
Name: a, dtype: int64

>>> df.loc[~df['b'].duplicated(), 'b']
(1, 2]    5
(3, 4]    6
Name: b, dtype: int64

>>> df.loc[~df['c'].duplicated(), 'c']
(1, 2]    7
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I looked into that, but that solution has two problems.

1.  It does not expand the time intervals to encompass the intervals that get removed.
2.  We only want to merge repeated data, not remove all duplicated data.